Reviews Rich Snippet for SAB (service area based) business
can someone confirm or deny my suspicion that reviews rich snippets are not showing up on SERP for SAB businesses? We had the schema for a while but none of our pages in SERP display reviews. When analyzing the companies that have them show up I noticed that all are tied to a specific local address. I would be grateful for any input.
